# How to show a list of values as a comma-separated list of strings in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to remove a comma from the last list after writingFile. How to specifically remove the comma from list?

```
Expected output

[Spa"24""Meta""Outram"1[("Colin",4),("Nixon",6),("Sam",5),("Petrina",7),("Justin",5)],

Spa"25""Zen""Outram"2[("Bryan",7),("Petrina",9),("Colin",4),("Nixon",7),("Sam",5)]]
```

```
Output achieved 

[Spa"24""Meta""Outram"1[("Colin",4),("Nixon",6),("Sam",5),("Petrina",7),("Justin",5)],

Spa"25""Zen""Outram"2[("Bryan",7),("Petrina",9),("Colin",4),("Nixon",7),("Sam",5)],]
```

```
-- turn original spa into String
spaStr :: Spa -> String
spaStr spa@(Spa rid br ar st s)
    = "Spa" ++ "\""++ rid ++ "\"" ++ "\"" ++ br ++ "\""++ "\""++ ar ++ "\"" ++ show st  ++ show s ++ "," ++"\n"

let newdB = ((addTspa rid br ar (read st))dB)
putStrLn $ spaStr newdB
writeFile "spa.txt" ("[" ++ spaStr newdB ++ "]")
```

Comment: is this impossible?

Comment: I’m finding it a bit difficult to understand what you’re asking for here. Exactly which list are you talking about, and do you want to remove an item or a comma from it? (The title says you want to remove an item, but your question asks about removing a comma.)

Comment: Your `spaStr` adds a comma at the end of each item , which looks odd at the end of a list of items. Is that your problem? (your title suggests something else entirely) If so, have a look at the `intersperse` function in `Data.List`, like in `concat $ intersperse ", " ["a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: yes, because I am trying to rewrite a text file to all have comma except the last entry. So I am not sure how to prevent the addition of comma at the end as it is going to be a long list, thus I need to find a way to remove the comma from last entry in order for the testdatabase to be readable. The list I am referring to is in testDatabase.

Comment: does the name make more sense now?

Comment: I am trying to add a new entry into a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, a possible approach is:

- Turn your `[Spa]` to `[String]` without adding any commas or newlines. This will generate a list like `["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]`
- Use `intersperse ",\n"` on that list to add that separator in the middle of adjacent elements. This will not add the separator to the end. You will get something like `["aaa", ",\n", "bbb", ",\n", "ccc"]`
- Use `concat` on the result, obtaining `"aaa,\nbbb,\nccc"`.
- Add the final `[` and `]`.

Here is an example which runs and produces your wanted output:

```
import Data.List (intersperse)

data Spa = Spa String String String Int [(String, Int)]

-- turn original spa into String
spaStr :: Spa -> String
spaStr spa@(Spa rid br ar st s)
    = "Spa" ++ "\""++ rid ++ "\"" ++ "\"" ++ br ++ "\""++ "\""++ ar ++ "\"" ++ show st  ++ show s

newDb :: [Spa]
newDb =
   [ Spa "24" "Meta" "Outram" 1
     [("Colin",4),("Nixon",6),("Sam",5),("Petrina",7),("Justin",5)]
   , Spa "25" "Zen" "Outram" 2
     [("Bryan",7),("Petrina",9),("Colin",4),("Nixon",7),("Sam",5)]
   ]

main :: IO ()
main =
    putStrLn $ "[" ++ concat (intersperse ",\n" $ map spaStr newDb) ++ "]"
```

Output:

```
[Spa"24""Meta""Outram"1[("Colin",4),("Nixon",6),("Sam",5),("Petrina",7),("Justin",5)],
Spa"25""Zen""Outram"2[("Bryan",7),("Petrina",9),("Colin",4),("Nixon",7),("Sam",5)]]
```